# MongoDB select via Java

Tags: java, mongodb

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient();
DB db = mongo.getDB("mytest");

DBCollection col = db.getCollection("testt");

//read example
DBObject query = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("$gte", "06/01/2016 00:00:00").add("$lte", "10/01/2016 00:00;00").get();
DBCursor cursor = col.find(query);

while(cursor.hasNext()) {
  System.out.println("docc:");
  System.out.println(cursor.next());
}
```

I am getting below exception while selecting data from MongoDB in Java.

> com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 2 and
>   error message 'unknown top level operator: $gte' on server
>   127.0.0.1:27017   at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:493)   at
>   com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:483)    at
>   com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:241)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:214)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:483)
>     at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:80)
>     at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:818)    at
>   com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:805)   at
>   com.mongodb.DBCursor.initializeCursor(DBCursor.java:851)  at
>   com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:152)   at
>   MongoFetch.main(MongoFetch.java:55)

Comment: Did that solve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

Well you query does not mention the field you are querying on - just the range, therefore mongoDB does not really know what to do. Try something like that

```
...
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("yourDateField", BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("$gte", fromDate).add("$lte", toDate).get());
DBCursor cursor = col.find(query);
...
```